# Cant get Android Project to Build in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, error-handling

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe', CommandLine='package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/User1/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'
```

I've installed Android SDK and JDK twice now, added the JAVA_HOME to the environment variables and found the programmes within Unity. What else am I getting wrong?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, however the sdk location is mixing forward and backward slashes in the same path: C:/Users/User1/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar

Comment: That may indicate that Unity failed to find `aapt.exe` in that location. From time to time, the Android SDK moves a build tool from one folder to another. After installing SDK tools, look for `aapt.exe` and see if you can move it (or link to it) in the location where Unity is trying to find it.